# How does iteration work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops, block

I've recently started coding Ruby and I'm having a mis-understanding with block parameters.
Take the following code for example:

```
h = { # A hash that maps number names to digits
:one => 1, # The "arrows" show mappings: key=>value
:two => 2 # The colons indicate Symbol literals
}
h[:one] # => 1. Access a value by key
h[:three] = 3 # Add a new key/value pair to the hash
h.each do |key,value| # Iterate through the key/value pairs
  print "#{value}:#{key}; " # Note variables substituted into string
end # Prints "1:one; 2:two; 3:three; "
```

I understand the general hash functionality, however I don't understand how `value` and `key` are set to anything. They are specified as parameters in the block, but the hash is never associated in any way with these parameters.

Comment: When it says `h.each do |key,value|` the association of `key,value` to `h` for the entire `do` block is defined on that line. The names `key` and `value` could be whatever you like.

Comment: If `h.each` looks too magical for then you could always use `h.each_pair`.

Comment: Ruby comes with IRB, which you can run from the command-line using `irb`. It lets you easily start playing with variables and assignments. It's a great tool when you want to learn these sorts of things.

Comment: You may want to accept answers, if they solve your problems. They're the tick icon next to each question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the Ruby block (Ruby's name for an anonymous function) syntax. And `key`, `value` are nothing but the arguments passed to the anonymous function.

`Hash#each` takes one parameter: A function which has 2 parameters, `key` and `value`.

So if we break it down into parts, this part of your code: `h.each`, is calling the `each` function on `h`. And this part of your code:

```
do |key, value| # Iterate through the key/value pairs
  print "#{value}:#{key}; " # Note variables substituted into string
end # Prints "1:one; 2:two; 3:three;
```

is the function passed to `each` as an argument and `key`, `value` are arguments passed to this function. It doesn't matter what you name them, first argument expected is *key* and second argument expected is *value*.

Lets draw some analogies. Consider a basic function:

```
 def name_of_function(arg1, arg1)
   # Do stuff
 end

 # You'd call it such:
 foo.name_of_function bar, baz # bar is becomes as arg1,  baz becomes arg2 

 # As a block:

 ooga = lambda { |arg1, arg2|
   # Do stuff
 }

 # Note that this is exactly same as:

 ooga = lambda do |arg1, arg2|
   # Do stuff
 end

 # You would call it such:

 ooga.call(bar, baz) # bar is becomes as arg1,  baz becomes arg2
```

So your code can also be written as:

```
print_key_value = lambda{|arg1, arg2| print "#{arg1}:#{arg2}"}
h = { 
  :one => 1,
  :two => 2
}

h.each &print_key_value
```

There are multiple ways in which the code inside a block can be executed:

```
  yield
  yield key, value # This is one possible way in which Hash#each can use a block
  yield item

  block.call
  block.call(key, value) # This is another way in which Hash#each can use a block
  block.call(item)
```

Answer (score 6):

The hash (`h`) is associated with the loop due to you calling `h.each` rather than calling `each` on something else. It's effectively saying, "For each key/value pair in `h`, let the `key` iteration variable be the key, let the `value` iteration variable be the value, then execute the body of the loop."

If that doesn't help, have a look at [this page on `each`](http://perl.about.com/od/rubytutorials/a/rubyeachloop_2.htm)... and if you can explain more about which bit you're finding tricky, we may be able to help more. (Well, others may be able to. I don't really know Ruby.)

Answer (score 1):

The hash is indeed associated with these parameters because you call h.each to iterate over the hash:

h.each <- here's the link you are missing

Perhaps it's easier for you if you start with an array instead:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.each do |v|
  puts v
end
```

and play around with this first (`each`, `each_with_index`, ...)

Comment: Ah yes - That makes sense. But how does it know to apply the hash's key to "key" and it's value to "value"? After all they are just parameters even if the hash is associated

Comment: @Joesavage1: Because you're saying to use the names "key" and "value" here: `|key,value|`. If you used `|k,v|` then the variables would be called `k` and `v` instead.

Answer (score 0):

when you call `h.each`, that's when you say that this is this specific `h` hash that you want to use for this each iteration.
Hence when you do that the `value` and `key` variables are assigned to the values in your hash, one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is about the variable names. The names have no significance. Only the order matters. Within `|...|` inside `each {...}`, the key and the value are given in that order. Since its natural to assign the variable name `key` to key and `value` to value, you often find it done like that. In fact, it can be anything else.

```
each{|k, v| ...}  # k is key, v is value
each{|a, b| ...}  # a is key, b is value
```

or even misleadingly:

```
each{|value, key| ...} # value is key, key is value
```